# Is it a good exercise for the eyes to work with different font sizes or would refocusing strain the eye?

Tags: computers, vision

In my work I deal with several screens, and recently I have started using different pieces of software for coding. When I installed the new one, I noticed that the font size there is a bit bigger, and I am mostly work with this one at the moment. However, whenever I need to take a look at the old code, my eyes feel a bit strange since the font there is smaller.

My original idea was to make the font in the old code bigger, on par with the new one, however I thought that it may be a good exercise for the eyes to refocus at different font sizes. Is it?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I suspect that it's no, it's not helpful. However, I use multiple monitors and have noticed that switching from one to another can be a bit tiresome on the eyes. I found that what's most helpful is making sure both monitors are the same brightness, contrast and color saturation levels. It can be difficult to achieve with some monitors, but the closer you can get, the better, especially brightness.

Comment: Tired intraocular and extraocular muscles need rest. Not exercise. Just close your eyes to rest them (ideally, after 20 minutes of computer use). Also, relax your face muscles and neck muscles. Getting 8 hours of uninterrupted sleep each night is also crucial to reduce strain.